# Is there any way to avoid trigger cascading in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a the following tables :

- **Table1** (Field_A)
- **Table2** (Field_B, and Field_A from the Table1 as a ForeignKey constraint with Cascade attribute)

**Table2** has a trigger that performs some operations when a row is being **deleted**.

Is there anyway to avoid execution of the trigger in Table2 when the origin of delete operation is Table1 cascading ?

Thank you.

Comment: Triggers can be disabled, ad hoc. Otherwise, you can built in intelligent code in your trigger, that operations on condition. The trigger may be fired, but you may decide what you let your trigger do, which includes : do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box way to do this, but you could make a package with a variable, which is set in one trigger and checked in the next.

Those package variables are session-specific, so you won't bother other sessions, although you should make sure that the variable is reset, otherwise stand-alone deletes may be recognised as cascaded deletes within the same session.

Roughly, it should look like this:

```
create package PKG_CASCADE as 
  V_YOURFLAG char(1);
end package;
/

create package body PKG_CASCADE as

begin
  V_YOURFLAG := 'N';
end;
/

create trigger TDB_Table1 before delete on Table1
begin
  begin
    PKG_CASCADE.V_YOURFLAG := 'Y';

    delete from Table2 .....;

    PKG_CASCADE.V_YOURFLAG := 'N';
  exception when others do
    PKG_CASCADE.V_YOURFLAG := 'N';
  end;
end;
/

create trigger TDB_Table2 before delete on Table2
begin
  if PKG_CASCASE.V_YOURFLAG <> 'Y' then
    -- Do you stuff.
  end if;
end;
/
```

I typed this without Oracle at hand, so please excuse me for any syntax errors.

For a more elaborate tutorial see:

- [PL/SQL Tutorial | PL/SQL Exception Handling](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-exception-handling.htm)
- [Using Package Variables to Store Global Data](http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_global_data.htm)